# No ObservableObject of type PageSettings found

Tags: swiftui, ios13

I want to change the value of my @EnvironmentObject using a different view to call it. But I get this error. Here's my syntaxes

**MY CLASS**

```
   class PageSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage = "splash"
    @Published var jobTitle = "Pick a job!"
}
```

**A VIEW** (In this view I get "Pick a job!" as a text and I want to change it when I clicked another option from another view called "JobTitleView")

```
    struct Test: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var title: PageSettings

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Button(action: {
                let alertHC = UIHostingController(rootView: JobTitleView())

                alertHC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 200)
                alertHC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen

                UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.present(alertHC, animated: true)
            })
            {
                Text(self.title.jobTitle)

                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
            }
        }.frame(height:50).font(.subheadline)
    }
}
```

**JOBTITLE VIEW**

```
struct JobTitleView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var title: PageSettings
    let options = ["Manager", "Employee"]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(options) { item in
            Button(action:{

                self.title.jobTitle = item
                UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {})
            }){
                Text(item).font(.custom("Avenir Next Regular", size: 30))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I pressed an item I got the following error:

*Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type PageSettings found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for PageSettings may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-39.4.3/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55*

PS. I got an extension to use a ForEach "without id"

```
extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        return self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the place where you create `Test` you have to use it as

```
Test().environmentObject(PageSettings())
```

and most probably in this custom creation as well (in view builder hierarchy environment object is injected automatically for subview, but in this case I suppose it is not)

```
let alertHC = UIHostingController(rootView: 
         JobTitleView().environmentObject(self.pageSettings))
```

Comment: do you know how can I inject the value for subview to my view?

because this works if I make this:
envar = "HI"
ViewA(envar)  -> ViewB(envar)

(I will get "HI" in my ViewB and I can change that value ONLY in ViewB, I want to change envar's value using my ViewB)